# Maven War Dependency on new Jar Project

Tags: maven

I've been asked to create a desktop installable version of a maven webapp of ours. This desktop project will basically setup an embedded Jetty web container and a JavaFX Webkit browser to display this webapp, i mean, just to have a feel to run like a desktop app, which it's not.

I am struggling a little bit in order to find the best solution to manage the WEB application dependency on this new Desktop project, because it's a WAR project.

So i need a way to do either of this:

1) Import the packed WAR file from the maven WEB project and be able to point it somehow to Jetty passing as a path or classpath resource

2) Import the WAR classes into this project, and the static content from this somehow.

This Desktop project is meant to be of JAR type.

How would you guys solve this?

Thank you so much